# Zero Values in array

Tags: java

After putting the functions in classes i get zero(0) results in my array. Why is that?
Nothing changed I just copy pasted them in the classes? Is there anything else I should put in the classes to make that work?

```
import java.util.*;//import library

class Input
{

    public Input (int size,int startV,int endingV)
      {

         //declarations of variables
        double difference;
        double[] array= new double[size];

        array[0]=startV;

     //calculating the difference to add on each number in the array
     difference=(endingV-startV)/size;

    for (int counter=1;counter<size;counter++) //for loop to fill the array
              {
        array[counter]=array[counter-1] + difference;           
          }


      }

    public Input enter(int size,int startV,int endingV)
      {

        //declarations of variables
        double difference;
        double[] array= new double[size];

        array[0]=startV;

             //calculating the difference to add on each number in the array
        difference=(endingV-startV)/size; 

            for (int counter=1;counter<size;counter++) //for loop to fill the array
        {
            array[counter]=array[counter-1] + difference;           
        }

            return this;
    }
}

class Show
{
    public Show (int size,double[] array)
    {

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) //for loop to print the array
            System.out.println("This is the array " + i+ ": " + array[i]);

    }

    public Show print(int size,double[] array)
    {

        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) //for loop to print the array
        System.out.println("This is the array " + i+ ": " + array[i]);

        return this;
    }
}

public class Assignment2 
{

    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        //declaring variables
        int startV,endingV;
        int size=0;



        System.out.print("Give the size of the array:");//Print message on screen
        size = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//asking for the size of array

            double[] array= new double[size]; //creation of array

    System.out.print("Give the starting value of the array:");
    startV = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//asking for the starting value of array

    System.out.print("Give the ending value of the array:");
    endingV = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();//asking for the last value of array

    //calling the functions from the other classes 

        Input enter= new Input(size,startV,endingV);
        Show print= new Show(size,array);

    }



}
```

Comment: If what i just pasted its not a prove that I am doing my homework then i don't know what to say m8

Comment: The question I am asking now its different from the one I asked before. Its just a repost of the code to ask a different question since my other post for the same code was edited for the needs of the question I asked before. Since I am asking a new question I was advised to do it to a a new post for the good of the community. Please if you don't have an answer to my question I would kindly ask you to stop spamming on my post .

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the following isn't what you want:

```
difference=(endingV-startV)/size;
```

Since `startV`, `endingV` and `size` are all integer, this uses integer (truncating) division.

Also, create and use a single `Scanner` instead of creating a new one every time you need to read a value.

Comment: Still I cant see why that's the reason i get 0 values in my array. I mean that maybe changes the result but doesn't explain why i get the 0.

Answer (score 0):

`//calling the functions from the other classes`

No, you don't. You just create instances.

Comment: That comment was from before didn't change it sorry :)

Comment: That does not change the situation. When you call new Input() you do not fill the array with values. The Input constructor does not know anything about your array. It creates its own array.